# cherrypy + sqlalchemy + sqlalchemy-datatables: unhashable type: dict

Tags: python, datatables, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to integrate jQuery datatables server side processing with cherrypy & sqlalchemy, and I'm getting an error about "unhashable type: 'dict'".

The code I've written looks like this:

```
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def GET(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with GetDb().ScopedSession("Fetching detail for main page") as session:
        # defining columns
        columns = [
            ColumnDT(dbModels.DatabaseModel.Field1),
            ColumnDT(dbModels.DatabaseModel.Field2),
            # ...
        ]

        query = session.query(dbModels.DatabaseModel)

        # GET parameters
        params = kwargs  # I think this is what's causing the issue.

        print("==========================")
        print(params)
        print("==========================")

        # instantiating a DataTable for the query and table needed
        rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)

        # returns what is needed by DataTable
        result = rowTable.output_result()
        print("==========================")
        print(result)
        print("==========================")
        return result
```

The result of the 'params' print looks like this (truncated somewhat):

```
{'draw': '1', 'columns[0][data]': '', 'columns[0][name]': '', 'columns[0][searchable]': 'true' }
```

And the result output looks like this:

```
{'draw': '1', 'recordsTotal': '125', 'recordsFiltered': '125', 'error': "unhashable type: 'dict'"}
```

My suspicion is that the DataTables() call doesn't like the 'jsonpath'-like GET parameter (see the "# I think this is what's causing the issue" part above), so I'm curious if there's a way I can have cherrypy return the **kwargs as nested key/value pairs, or a function to convert kwargs into a nested dictionary -- or, if I'm completely wrong and this is a different error altogether. :)

Thanks!

More data if it helps:

The webpage rendering shows an alert saying:

```
DataTables warning: table id=active-jobs - unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Clicking OK yields a type error in the datatables code:

```
datatables.min.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at vb (datatables.min.js:52)
    at datatables.min.js:49
    at i (datatables.min.js:47)
    at Object.success (datatables.min.js:48)
    at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
    at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)
vb @ datatables.min.js:52
(anonymous) @ datatables.min.js:49
i @ datatables.min.js:47
success @ datatables.min.js:48
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3268
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3398
done @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9305
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9548
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9567
ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
sa @ datatables.min.js:48
lb @ datatables.min.js:49
P @ datatables.min.js:41
T @ datatables.min.js:43
ha @ datatables.min.js:60
e @ datatables.min.js:105
(anonymous) @ datatables.min.js:105
each @ jquery-3.3.1.js:354
each @ jquery-3.3.1.js:189
n @ datatables.min.js:95
h.fn.DataTable @ datatables.min.js:177
RebuildTable @ (index):128
(anonymous) @ (index):266
mightThrow @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3534
process @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3602
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3640
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3268
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3398
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3406
fire @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3268
fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3398
ready @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3878
completed @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3888
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback, if any.

Comment: There isn't one.  This isn't excepting, the "unhashable type: 'dict'" is from the rowTable.output_result().

Comment: Well, upon further reflection, the javascript is causing a stack trace; so I'll add that to the description in case it's useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  One of my columns was of type "JSONType" from sqlalchemy_utils, and the sqlalchemy-datatables class wasn't handling that it was getting a 'dict' back for the JSON data.

I solved this - for better or for worse - by not including that in my columns, and instead having a hand-crafted column that I filled an object out with the details that I needed.